# Fun with Ember, CoffeeScript precedence

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

IF

```
 !Ember.isEmpty @get('a') #-> true
```

AND

```
 !Ember.isEmpty @get('b') #-> false
```

Then why

```
 !Ember.isEmpty @get('a') and !Ember.isEmpty @get('b') #-> true
```

Or is it my CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you're having is with Coffeescript precedence.  Your code in javascript is:

```
!Ember.isEmpty(this.get('a') && !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('b')));
```

You need to add parens to make the order of operations more explicit here:

```
!Ember.isEmpty(@get('a')) and !Ember.isEmpty(@get('b'))
```

So in javascript it is:

```
!Ember.isEmpty(this.get('a')) && !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('b'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything after `.isEmpty` is interpreted as arguments for that function call. If that's not what you want, you need brackets or groups.

Also, you should use `not` instead of `!`, because of clarity.

If you only use brackets to group calls and their arguments, it becomes clearer:

```
not Ember.isEmpty(@get 'a') and not Ember.isEmpty @get 'b'
```

Or even clearer, although a bit lispy

```
(not Ember.isEmpty @get 'a') and not Ember.isEmpty @get 'b'
```